# SQL Server window functions: building up a history string

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table of longitudinal data that looks like this:

[image]

where `id` is the partition variable, `period` is the time dimension, and `val` is the observation value.

I want to build up a history of `val` for each panel of `id`, like this:

[image]

I'm trying to do this with SQL window functions and not a cursor, but the issue I keep running into is the self-referential nature of the `hist` column definition. It almost seems like I'd have to create one row/column per period.  For example, the closest I could come was this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.my_try', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE dbo.my_try; 
GO
SELECT
    id, period, val, 
    CASE
        WHEN (
            period = MIN(period) 
                OVER (PARTITION by id order by period ROWS 
                BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        ) THEN CAST (val AS VARCHAR(60))
        ELSE NULL           
    END AS hist  
INTO my_try
FROM my_test

SELECT
    id, period, val, 
    CASE
        WHEN (
            period = MIN(period) OVER 
            (PARTITION by id order by period ROWS 
            BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
        ) THEN hist 
        ELSE (
            CONCAT(
                val, ' | ', LAG(hist, 1) OVER (PARTITION by id order by period)
            )
        )

    END AS hist2
FROM my_try
```

[image]

I would have to spool out the iteration and do a `hist3`, etc. for it to finally work.

Is it possible to accomplish this with SQL window functions, or is cursor the only route?

---

**Sample Data**

Here is some code to generate the original table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_test (
    id INT,
    period INT,
    val INT 
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @id INT = 1;
    DECLARE @period INT = 1;

    WHILE @id <= 3
    BEGIN
        SET @period = 1 
        WHILE @period <= 3
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO my_test VALUES (@id, @period, @period * POWER(10, @id))
            SET @period = @period + 1
        END

        SET @id = @id + 1
    END
END
```

Comment: Looks like a recursive cte would make short work of this. Can you post your sample data in a consumable format so we don't have to type it all out? And I would have to ask, how to create the screenshot data? Or was that using a cursor that you want to eliminate.

Comment: yeah recursive query is a solution. However if you are working with sql server 2017 then they have aggregation function for strings [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql)

Comment: @SeanLange I posted some code to generate the sample data.  As for the screenshot of the desired outcome, I just created that manually.  Thx

Comment: Do you always have exactly three periods for each id or does that change in your real data?

Comment: It changes in the real data, unfortunately

Comment: @Irdis I wish I could learn and use this new `string_agg`, it looks good -
 unfortunately we are not on 2017 yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need recursion here. You can leverage STUFF pretty easily. Of course if you are on 2017 you can use string_agg as suggested above. But if you are like me and your company is not the fastest to adopt the latest and greatest you can use this.

```
select t1.id
    , t1.period
    , t1.val
    , STUFF((select ' | ' + convert(varchar(10), val)
            from my_test t2
            where t2.id = t1.id
                and t2.period <= t1.period
            order by t1.period
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 3,'')
from my_test t1
order by t1.id
    , t1.period
```

Comment: seems like FOR XML PATH is really what makes this possible?

Comment: @DaniDev yes, it actually takes both STUFF and FOR XML.

Comment: Thanks you, this will come in very handy in some point in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments try using recursive query

```
with cte as(
select id, [period], val, convert(varchar(max), val) as agg from my_try where [period] = 1
union all
select t.id, t.[period], t.val, CONCAT(c.agg, ' | ', t.val) from my_try t join cte c on c.[period] +1 = t.[period] and c.id = t.id
)
select * from cte order by id, [period]
```